# Problema al consumir un web service de pagos

Tags: php, webservice

Estoy tratando de consumir una web service para pagos online con PHP, según la guía son solo 4 sencillos pasos. 
http://wpp.sandbox.mit.com.mx/genera.jsp

1. Generar una cadema xml con los datos de pago.
2. Encriptar la cadena
3. Enviar al servidor la cadena encriptada con un formato específico
4. Desencriptar la cadena retornada por el servidor

Solo que en el paso 4 el servidor me retorna una cadena vacía.

```
public function prueba()
{
    $xmlOriginal= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><P><business><id_company>SNBX</id_company><id_branch>01SNBXBRNCH</id_branch><user>SNBXUSR01</user><pwd>SECRETO</pwd></business><url><reference>FACTURA999</reference><amount>2500.00</amount><moneda>MXN</moneda><canal>W</canal><omitir_notif_default>1</omitir_notif_default><promociones>C,3,6,9</promociones><st_correo>1</st_correo><fh_vigencia>24/06/2018</fh_vigencia><mail_cliente>nospam@gmail.com</mail_cliente><datos_adicionales><data id="1" display="true"><label>Talla</label><value>Grande</value></data><data id="2" display="false"><label>Color</label><value>Azul</value></data></datos_adicionales></url></P>';
    $key = '**************************';

    $xmlEncriptado= $this->encriptar($xmlOriginal, $key);

    $data = '<pgs><data0>SNDBX123</data0><data>'.$xmlEncriptado.'</data></pgs>';

    $headers = [
        'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
        'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ];

    $url = "https://bc.mitec.com.mx/p/gen";

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    $ch_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $ch_error = curl_error($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    dd([$ch_error, $ch_info, $response]);

    $response = $this->desencriptar($response, $key);
}

protected function encriptar($plaintext, $key128){
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-128-cbc'));
    $cipherText = openssl_encrypt ( $plaintext, 'AES-128-CBC', hex2bin($key128), 1, $iv);
    return base64_encode($iv.$cipherText);
}

public static function desencriptar($encodedInitialData, $key128){
    $encodedInitialData =  base64_decode($encodedInitialData);
    $iv = substr($encodedInitialData,0,16);
    $encodedInitialData = substr($encodedInitialData,16);
    $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encodedInitialData, 'AES-128-CBC', hex2bin($key128), 1, $iv);
    return $decrypted;
}
```

Al hacer `dd()` o `var_dump()` de `$response` es string esta vacío

```
dd([$ch_error, $ch_info, $response]);
```

Se supone que al desencriptar `$reponse` debo obtner un xml con una liga como esta http://wpp.sandbox.mit.com.mx/i/SNDBX001

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero... ¿es un problema de la respuesta en sí,  o es un problema al llamar `desencriptar`? Un `var_dump($response);` después de `$response = curl_exec($ch);` muestra datos o no?

Comment: El problema esta en la respuesta del servidor que regresa una cadena vacia, el var_dump($response) muestra ''

Comment: Entonces tienes que ver del lado del Webservice, si es que lo has programado tú. Puede que no esté aceptando la `$key` o algo así. Busca información en un `var_dump($ch_info);` y en `var_dump($ch_error);` o en el log de errores.

Comment: en la imagen que puse en la pregunta el array[0] es el var_dump( $ch_error)  el cual es un string vacío, lo que entiendo que no hubo errores, array[1] es el var_dump($ch_info) y el array[2] (recuadro rojo) ahi debería haber una cadena de $response, y donde checo el log de errores?

Comment: Generalmente en la carpeta donde tienes tu archivo php hay un archivo llamado `error_log` o algo parecido, donde se registran los errores. Habría que revisar al final de ese archivo, donde aparecerían los últimos  errores ocurridos. Esa información es muy valiosa para saber lo que podría estar ocurriendo. Aunque analizando lo que pones en la imagen, todo parece correcto del lado de la petición. En los datos de la imagen, el `ssl_verify_result` con resultado `0` podría hacer pensar que no ha ocurrido verificación en el Webservice. Convendría quizá contactarlos.

Comment: Supongo que tu `$xmlOriginal` tiene los datos correctos en claves como `user`, `pwd`... etc.

Comment: Supongo que en `encriptar` tienes el código como lo explican ellos (paso 2). En el paso 3, la URL que ellos indica es esta `http://wpp.sandbox.mit.com.mx/gen` mientras que en tu imagen se ve otra, no sé si eso tenga que ver. En ese mismo paso 3 el código que ellos muestran es distinto del tuyo, ellos no indican el uso de `cURL`. Y por último, en `desencriptar` imagino que tienes el código como indican ellos.

Comment: si, al parecer la falla esta en las lineas de cURL, ya hice la prueba en postman enviando la cadena encriptada apuntando a `http://wpp.sandbox.mit.com.mx/gen` y si retorna otra cadena encriptada donde esta contenida los datos que requiero, seguiré buscando donde esta el error concretamente.